# ¿Por qué cuestionan las respuestas dadas sin proponer una respuesta efectiva?

Tags: discusión

¿Por qué cuestionan las respuestas dadas sin proponer una respuesta efectiva?

Hace poco me paso que se ponene a criticar las respuesta de una pregunta pero sin aportar una respuesta efectiva, creo yo que la mejor forma de dejar en claro que una respuesta no es acertada es dar la mejor respuesta no solo cuestionarla sin aportar nada.

Comment: Estás generalizado, pero supongo que te refieres a un hecho concreto que te afecto a ti y pretendes exponer como algo cotidiano. No creo que pase lo que dices y te recomiendo que si tienes una queja, uses las herramientas que pone la comunidad a tu disposición, como los reportes, por ejemplo.

Comment: No pretendo exponerlo como algo cotidiano, solo formule la pregunta para que quienes se dedican a contestar así me respondan porque lo hacen.

Comment: Pero, ¿a quién te refieres? ¿Quién debe contestar tu pregunta? ¿Es una pregunta retórica? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de un cuestionamiento a una "respuesta dada sin proponer una respuesta efectiva"?

Comment: Ejemplo: ¿Cúanto es 2+2? Respuesta 4; 
Alguien comenta: "Esa no es la respuesta esta mal" 
¿Entonces cúal es la respuesta? 
Alguien comenta:"No se, pero esa no es la respuesta"

Comment: En ese caso especifico tienes razón. ¿Eso fue lo que paso, a ti, una vez?

Comment: Se refiere a mi, y los comentarios en cuestión los pueden encontrar aquí: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/57450/18951.

Comment: Es lo que he visto en varias preguntas, no solo a mi, pero por primera vez me toco a mi.

Comment: No me refiero a ti @sstan pero si a ti te queda el saco.

Comment: Admito que te di duro, mas de lo usual para mi :) Te pido perdon. Algo en que trabajar. Pero si lo que mencionas se trata de otro caso, sería bueno que compartas un enlace al ejemplo especifico que tienes en mente para que los demás puedan comentar basado en hechos, no en interpretación. A veces, sin querer, cuando uno se frustra, uno tiende a cambiar un poco los hechos (me ha pasado) :)

Comment: No quiero que me digan juicios, si no al contrario tu respuesta personal como tu lo dijiste, a ti a veces te frustrar y actuas diferente o cosas así entonces quiero saber a los demas que les hace comportarse así para entendernos mejor y no tomar nada a personal.

Comment: ¿Todo esto solo porque alguien alguna vez le contestó al OP de forma "brusca"? Esperemos que a mas personas les quede el saco y le contesten.

Comment: Imagina que estás programando algo en tu trabajo y alguien te dice: "está mal". Independientemente de si luego te dan alternativa, ¿acaso no es positivo tener esa valiosa información para afinar la respuesta dada? ¿O es mejor ir de cabeza hacia una solución errónea? Tómate los comentarios como algo relacionado con tu publicación, no como algo relacionado con tu persona.

Comment: Somos ingenieros, nos basamos sobre **hechos**. Al evitar poner un hecho, suena como un cuento, y es difícil comprender la situación y se presta demasiado a opiniones e interpretaciones con muchas alas para volar. Asimismo, recomiendo que lo apuntes como una crítica constructiva y que nos ayude como comunidad a afrontar estos temas, actualmente suena más a una queja de algo que no sabemos qué sucedió y que quizás si vuelve a suceder no tenemos las herramientas para detectarlo y haremos lo que c/u crea conveniente.

Answer (score 3):

Obviamente, no puedo generalizar por los demás, pero en mi caso, sucede a veces que la pregunta no tiene respuesta posible hasta que OP agregue más detalles. O tal vez no es que sea imposible, sino que, por la misma falta de detalles, mi respuesta no sería mucho más que un adivinar de lo que es el problema y la solución. Puede que sea correcto, pero puede que no.

Con ese tipo de preguntas, típicamente no contesto. Prefiero pedirle a OP que agregue los detalles que faltan para que pueda dar una respuesta acertada.

Cuando veo que otras personas lanzan respuestas del tipo *intenta esto o aquello*, o sea adivinando no más, no me agrada mucho, pero generalmente no voto ni a favor ni en contra en esas situaciones.

Sin embargo, si aquellas respuestas, sea que estén adivinando o no, son obviamente incorrectas, y hay buenas razones para concluir que son incorrectas, puede que le dé un voto negativo, pero que lo haga o no, sí trato de siempre dejar un comentario explicando porqué la respuesta es incorrecta. O si alguien ya dejó un comentario al respecto, voto a favor del comentario.

En estos casos, no siento que el que vote en contra o deje un comentario bajo una respuesta por ser incorrecta me obliga a mi a dejar una respuesta también. No pienso que una cosa tenga que ver con la otra.

Al final, mi prioridad es que el contenido de este sitio sea de calidad para la comunidad. Y las 3 formas principales que uso para tratar de favorecer la calidad del contenido de este sitio son las siguientes:

1. Dejando una respuesta de calidad cuando es posible
2. Votando a favor de *todas* las respuestas que sean útiles (desde mi punto de vista) y que no sean duplicados exactos de otras respuestas, sea que yo haya contestado ya en la misma pregunta o no.
3. Tal vez votando en contra, pero siempre tratando de dejar un comentario explicativo bajo las respuestas que considero incorrectas.

Y, saliéndome un poco de tema, menciono de paso que nunca voto ni a favor ni en contra de una pregunta o respuesta basado en los votos de los demás, los comentarios de los demás, ni siquiera según lo que dice OP que le funciona o no (a menudo OP no tiene el mejor criterio) y aun menos porque me cae bien o mal un usuario. Siempre voto según mi evaluación personal del contenido de la pregunta o respuesta. Y particularmente en el caso de las respuestas, solo voto si considero que tengo suficientes conocimientos para dar una evaluación justa de la calidad de la respuesta.

A mi parecer, votar a favor o en contra usando criterios que no tienen nada que ver con la calidad del contenido causan daño al sitio y a la comunidad. Hasta votar a favor de preguntas o respuestas de usuarios nuevos solo porque son nuevos aunque el contenido sea malo, aunque parezca inocente, también hace daño. Igual que un padre que no disciplina a su hijo porque tiene miedo que se vaya de casa, al final, resulta ser una falta de amor al hijo porque no aprende a mejorar.

Yo quisiera que otros compartan mis criterios, pero acepto que no es el caso, y que así funciona este sitio que es para beneficio de *toda* la comunidad, pero moderada por ella misma también, para bien o para mal.